# Nth-child does not change colour for odd and even

Tags: html, css, django

This a Django project, in which I loop over folders and files. The background colour of each file should be different. For example, the odd ones should be purple and the even ones should be blue. But they are all shown as purple.

Here is the file div from HTML:

```
<div class="each_key">{{file}}</div>
```

Here is the styling in CSS:

```
.each_key:nth-child(odd){
    text-align: left;
    width:197px;
    height:42px;
    background-color: purple;
    padding:10px;
}

.each_key:nth-child(even){
    text-align: left;
    width:197px;
    height:42px;
    background-color: blue;
    padding:10px;
}
```

I've also tried "nth-of-type" and it still gives me purple instead of changing to purple and then blue.

Comment: Your code seems to be working as intended. Check out this codepen: https://codepen.io/ChenBri/pen/PoawwBb

Comment: Could you go into your browser’s devtools inspect facility and see exactly what HTML is being produced. It may be that all the divs with that class are first children.

Answer (score 0):

You can use (2n+1) and (2n)

```css
.each_key:nth-child(2n+1){
    text-align: left;
    width:197px;
    height:42px;
    background-color: purple;
    padding:10px;
}

.each_key:nth-child(2n){
    text-align: left;
    width:197px;
    height:42px;
    background-color: blue;
    padding:10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="each_key"></div>
<div class="each_key"></div>
<div class="each_key"></div>
<div class="each_key"></div>
<div class="each_key"></div>
<div class="each_key"></div>
<div class="each_key"></div>
```

Comment: The `odd` and `even` keywords should be doing the same thing. If he can't see the correct style with `.each_key:nth-child(odd)` the same thing will occur with `.each_key:nth-child(2n)`

Comment: Your code is working. My answer's an alternative. Have you tried to clear your browser cache ?

Comment: Yes, I've tried clearing the cache but there seems to be an issue with the parent divs. CSS cannot separate the class "each_key". Therefore everything is displayed in purple.